# I am on H-1B visa. Can I invest in a business run by my H4 wife?

Tags: united-states, investing, small-business, h-1b-visa, immigration

I am on H-1B since October 2017. My wife is expecting her EAD in August 2018. Can I invest in a business run by her?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think that you would not be allowed to invest in your wife's business in the same way that you might invest in anyone else's business?

Answer (score 3):

There’s no restrictions for you. However, your wife should be very careful about doing anything that may seem like employment or self-employment before she gets her EAD.

It might seem silly or paranoid but her response to whether she’s ever worked while not authorized to could torpedo her residency visa.